# rewrite https and www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

now I have a website https.

http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com = OK !

But, I have a problem with **www**
://example.com -> s://example.com = not good

I would like to have this redirection below :
://example.com -> s://www.example.com

How with RewriteCond and RewriteRule ? Help me plz !

Thanks !

Comment: I have no idea what your asking.  show code if you have it.  take with the language if you can and specific library if one is being used.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]

Comment: Ok, sorry not abile to help here, not familiar with the apache rewrite rules.  sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To enforce https on all requests and redirect to *www*.example.com

```
# force https and www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# if already https without www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !