# htaccess - modify current file to 301-redirect all traffic to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

this is my current .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}   (.*)ApacheBench(.*)    [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* h++p://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.seconddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ h++p://firstdomain.com/path/to/somewhere [L,R=301,NC]

php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value upload_max_filesize 5000M
```

What I want to do is, that all traffic coming to firstdomain.com to be redirected to https://firstdomain.com.

So:

- h++p://firstdomain.com
- h++p://www.firstdomain.com
- h++ps://www.firstdomain.com

all should be redirected (301 redirect) to

- h++ps://firstdomain.com

How I need to modify it? I tried it myself already before, but then I always receive a redirect error that seems to be unable to end and therefor the browser stops resolving the domain then.

Comment: As it happens, I answered a similar answer recently. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37647197/1741542

Comment: unfortunately, its not working. i always receive loop errors only. i tried now like 20 different settings that are spread all over stackoverflow. always just loop errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?firstdomain.com$ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seconddomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

you can try it.